# SignInManager always returns SignInResult.Succeeded = false for TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync() and TwoFactorSignInAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

We have a problem with an application that uses ASP.NET Core Identity with a custom user store. It's configured to use cookie authentication with 1h sliding expiration. Also, 2FA is activated site-wide, so every user account needs to add a 2FA token when registering.

The main problem of the application is, that the user gets logged out after 30 minutes. Even if you were active in Minute 29. When we reduce the sliding expiration to a smaller amount, e.g. 6 minutes, the sliding works, but only for 30 minutes, then it logs the user out again.

We currently suspect that the problem lies in the way 2FA is handled. The application doesn't use the 2FA-specific Identity methods (like `SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync()`). Instead, `SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false, "pwd")` is used when the username/password is correct, then redirects the user to the form to enter the 2FA token. The 2FA token is then verified by some custom code and when successful it uses `SignInManager.SignOutAsync()` first (to remove the "amr=pwd" cookie) and then `SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false, "mfa")` to get the "amr=mfa" cookie.

So, we thought we need to change the 2FA implementation to use the 2FA-specific methods from Identity instead. We tried to stick to the [Microsoft Identity UI sample template](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4). But when using `SignInManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync()` we always get a `SignInResult` with `Succeeded` set to `false`. We also tried `SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync()`, but with the same result.

We debugged for hours, even inside the ASP.NET source files, but we couldn't figure out why the application behaves that way. Did someone experience something similar or knows the cause of some of the described behaviors?

The application **Startup.cs**

```
// Use Identity Framework but with a custom User and Role store instead of Entity Framework
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddUserStore<UserStore>()
    .AddRoleStore<RoleStore>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Register UserManager and SignInManager facades
services.AddScoped<IUserManager, UserManagerFacade>();
services.AddScoped<ISignInManager, SignInManagerFacade>();

// Configure password hashing
services.AddSingleton<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>, IdentityPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Accounts/Login");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/AccessDenied");
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

**Login.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{ 
    var user = await this.userManager.FindByNameAsync(this.Email);
    await this.signInManager.SignInAsync(user, "pwd");
    return this.Redirect("LoginWithMfa");
}
```

**LoginWith2fa.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var user = await this.userManager.FindByNameAsync(this.User.Identity?.Name);

    var smsTokenCode = GetSmsTokenCode();    
    if (smsTokenCode?.Code == this.Code)
    {
        await this.signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        await this.signInManager.SignInAsync(user, "mfa");

        var claims = await this.userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
        return this.Redirect(ClaimBasedRedirects.RedirectPathAfterLogin(claims));
    }

    return this.Page();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your login code?

Comment: Yes, thank you. See my edit.

Comment: Hi. Did you get any solution. I am also facing same problem

Comment: We ended up using the `SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync()` method instead.